# Node.js program does not run the `finally {}` block after `try {}` and exit with code 0

Tags: node.js, rxjs

Today I'm writing some code with RxJS in Node.js and got very wired result: The program run the `try{}` block but did not run the `finally{}` block at all, exit with code 0 right inside the `try{}` block.

After making my code short, in order to reproduce this issue, the steps are:

1. first create a `BehaviorSubject` named `subject`
2. call `subject.asObservable().share()` and get a Observable named `obs`
3. call `obs.subscribe()`
4. call `await obs.first().toPromise()`

Then, at last, the program acts a very wired behavior: exit the `try {}` block without running the code inside the following `finally {}` block.

The TypeScript code to reproduce it is as the following: run it, then you will get a one line output: `1. BEFORE TRY`, which is not expected!

```
import {
  BehaviorSubject,
}                     from 'rxjs/Rx'

async function main() {
  const subject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(-1)
  const obs = subject.asObservable().share()

  /**
   * if comment the following line, this program will output right as the following three lines:
   *
   * 1. BEFORE TRY
   * 2. AFTER TRY
   * 3. FINALLY
   *
   * otherwise, the output will only be:
   *
   * 1. BEFORE TRY
   *
   * very wired!
   *
   */
  obs.subscribe()

  try {
    console.log('1. BEFORE TRY')

    await obs.first().toPromise()

    console.log('2. AFTER TRY')
  } finally {
    console.log('3. FINALLY')
  }

}

main()
```

My question is: **How could the Node.js exit inside a `try{}` block without running the `finally{}` block, with the exit code 0?**

Does there anyone have ideas?

Env:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin zixia-pro.lan 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Tue Jan 30 11:27:06 PST 2018; root:xnu-3789.73.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ node --version
v9.8.0
$ grep rxjs ../package.json 
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6"
```

## UPDATE

With the answer from @martin, I realized that this is the behavior of Node.js.

I write a reproducible program to demo how to exit the Node.js right in the `try{}` block and exit with code 0 without run the `finally{}` block, it's very simple: await a never resolve Promise.

```
async function main() {
  try {
    await new Promise(r => console.log('IN TRY BLOCK'))
  } finally {
    console.log('IN FINALLY BLOCK')
  }
}

main()
```

The above program will only output `IN TRY BLOCK` and exit with code 0, without output `IN FINALLY BLOCK` at all.

For the readers who feels this is strange too, I had also opened a issue for node at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/19929

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually correct behavior due to the operators you use.

You're creating a `BehaviorSubject(-1)` that emits `-1` to every new subscriber. Then you have `share()` that **keeps always only one subscription to its source Observable**.

And here the most important thing. When you use `obs.subscribe()` it makes `share` to subscribe to its source (`subject` in fact) that emits `-1` immediately but the value isn't printed anywhere because you used an empty subscriber with `.subscribe()`.

Then you create another subscriber with `await obs.first().toPromise()` but there's still the first subscriber subscribed so `share()` maintains this single one subscription to `subject` so the source `BehaviorSubject` never emits again which means the Promise in `.toPromise()` is never resolved so `await` keeps waiting forever.

However if you use instead of `obs.subscribe()` for example:

```
obs.take(1).subscribe(console.log);
```

See console output: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-pev27v?file=index.ts

... you'll see the expected output because `take(1)` unsubscribes right after receiving `-1` and then the second subscriber `toPromise()` makes `share()` to subscribe to `subject` again which emits `-1` and the Promise is resolved successfully.

Comment: If the `.toPromise()` will never be resolved, the program should await there forever. However, the result is that the program exited with code 0. Please run the code and you will find out that it exited immediately.

Comment: These are two different things. The `main` method is `async` so it just returns a Promise and the execution continues. The Promise however is still unresolved and `await` is waiting forever. You can see here that anything after `await` is never executed: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs5-pev27v?file=index.ts.
When the program ends means there are no more event in the even loop (which is true in the demo) but that's unrelated to this example.

Comment: Could you please explain why this piece of code is not executed?
 `console.log('2. AFTER TRY')`

Comment: Because it's executed only after the previous Promise is resolved because of `await`

Comment: No, I can not agree with you about that. I had just tried to replace the `await obs.first().toPromise()` by `await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 60000))`, the program will not exit and after wait 60 seconds, it printed all the console.log outputs.

Comment: That's because `setTimeout` creates another event that is scheduled in 60s. In your demo there're no more events in the event loop so it ends. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve? Why do you create and Observable to then immediately transform it to a Promise?

You create an Observable if you need to deal with "streams of events".

This is an example of using Observables, derived somehow from yours

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/Rx'

const subject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(-1)
const obs = subject.asObservable().share();

console.log('1. BEFORE SUBCRIPTION');
obs
.subscribe(
    aNumber => console.log('2. PROCESSING SUBCRIPTION', aNumber),
    err => console.error(err),
    () => console.log('3. COMPLETED OBSERVABLE')
)

subject.next(0);
subject.next(1);
subject.next(2);
subject.complete();
```

Comment: I make the code short to demonstrate that it will exit immediately, without running the code in `finally {}` block, which is very wired.